# Getting error "Failed to remove some directories" while installing opencv4nodejs

Tags: node.js, opencv, appium

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> npm install -g opencv4nodejs
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\deepakv\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\opencv4nodejs',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'C:\Users\deepakv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\opencv4nodejs\node_modules\opencv-build'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4082,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EBUSY',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\deepakv\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\opencv4nodejs\\node_modules\\opencv-build'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\deepakv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\opencv4nodejs
```

Installed
Node Version : v14.17.1
Python Version: 2.7
Appium: 1.21.0

Comment: Followed @Raghwendra but still had errors (possibly for different folders). Restarted the OS and tried `npm install` again. This time got one directory that failed to remove. The error is `ebusy` so maybe if I tried again it would not be busy. Ran `npm install` again and no error message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to resolve this error:

> Step 1: Delete node_modules
> Step 2: Delete package-lock.json
> Step 3: run "npm install" command to install all the project dependencies in one shot.

It will run perfectly fine.

Comment: This solved it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

1 - Remove the Directory 'opencv4nodejs' manually
2 - After deleting the directory, return to the terminal and run the command: npm install
*(For me this solved it!)*

This alone should resolve it.
If that doesn't work, you can do the following:

1 - Delete the 'node_modules' folder manually and the package
2 - Run the command: npm init
3 - Install all libraries again

And if it still doesn't work, then before doing the first step, give full permission on the project folder you are creating first of all.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I was unable to get this to work, even after following all the steps as suggested by Geraldo Meldo. So while this is not an answer to your problem, the workaround for me was to use yarn instead. It installed my project first time without any issues.

To install yarn globally:

> npm install -g yarn

To install your project using yarn:

> yarn install

I am starting to use yarn more and more as I find npm is giving me more issues than in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Another common reason for that error is that there might be a package-lock.json file generated within the project folder. To reinstall all the modules again, you may have to delete that file along with the package.json. Then, the npm install command will install all the required dependencies for the project.

Answer (score 0):

Followed @Raghwendra but still had errors (possibly for different folders). Restarted the OS, opened `vscode` terminal and tried `npm install` again. This time got one directory that failed to remove as opposed to multiple last time.

...The error is `ebusy` so maybe if I tried again it, whatever it was, would not be busy? Ran `npm install` again and no error message.

Answer (score -1):

just install Node again It worked for me